# kendoGrid using the html tag data-section

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Within my web application we use this html tag data-section='admin' for it not to display controls in the public side of the site. I was thinking that I would be able to use it within a template column so it would not display the remove column. In there another way to use this data-section in the template column?

```
if (!kendoGrid) {
    $("#kgridPresentation").kendoGrid({
        scrollable: false,
        toolbar: ["search"],
        columns: [
            {
                template: function (dataItem) {
                    return "<div align='center' data-section='admin'><a data-section='admin'><span data-section='admin' class='btn btn-red btn-custom' onclick=\"deletePresentation(" + dataItem.MeetingPresentationId + ", 'false')\"> <i class='fa fa-times'></i></span></a></div>";
                },
                title: "Remove",
                width: "73px"
            },
            {
                field: "PresentationTitle",
                title: "Presentation Title"
            },
            {
                template: function (dataItem) {
                    return "<a href=/Shared/Download.ashx?FileManagerId=" + dataItem.FileManager.FileManagerId + ">" + dataItem.FileManager.FileName + "</a>";
                },
                field: "FileManager.FileName",
                title: "File Name"
            },
            {
                field: "PresentationAuthor",
                title: "Presentation Speaker"
            }
        ],
        noRecords: {
            template: "No Result Found."
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is a function that returns the list of columns with a boolean parameter isAdminSection.

There are many ways to **visually** hide some columns, like [columns.hidden](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.hidden), width 0 etc., but a visitor with basic knowledge of CSS and developer tools could easily modify it and access the admin's options. This can be acceptable for you, if for example the functionality of deleting a presentation is always correctly authenticated on the back-end and would just return a HTTP 403 error for that user. It is however better to not render that column in the first place.